# My display twinkles on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: drivers, xorg, display, amd-graphics, 16.10

Display twinkles. I tried also with live version. With 16.04 there was no problem, but 16.10 twinkles. It stops twinkling, if there are changes on the screen, like scrolling or even mouse cursor moving. And then continues. It is seen better on dark colors.
I use notebook with hybrid video card, Radeon HD 8750M & Intel

```
    lspci -nnk | grep VGA -A3
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 09)
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [1025:082a]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

I tried to boot with an old 4.4.0-43 Kernel and it worked fine. So, the problem is somehow connected to the 4.8.0-22 Kernel.